# Steam API: Get current UTC DateTime

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

Good Day

This might be a simple question, but I just don't see this on the steam api documentation. I would like to retrieve the current UTC datetime from the steam api to enable some date specific features in my game and for obvious reasons I don't want to use the local computer datetime.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UTC datetime is the same everywhere in the world. If you specify the timezone, then you can access it from anywhere...

Comment: Thanks I understand that. I don't know which api function to call to get the current date from steam.

Answer (score 1):

found this, didn't get the answer, obviously it's too late for you but for anyone who's looking for it in the future :
SteamUtils.GetServerRealTime() will return the time in seconds since January 1st, 1970

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer and the documentation does not help, I was using the endpoint GetNewsForApp (v0002)